# Java Error in an XML file: aborting build

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I downloaded an android app so I could learn how to build map apps, and I need some help getting this running well. I have added the necessary libraries, and configured AVD. Now I need to get it to run but I keep running into the error below and need some help figuring this one out. Doing project cleans has not helped solve this one.

Where do I look for the problem in this case? I delete the main.xml.out file, run it, it is recreated and then the same error. What do I do to get to the main problem? And what could it be?

```
 ---this is the content of my main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0yNvLwdK_rMeMIYkMdOTNTttBcxQ0O_rgNLE_Mw"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the error log

```
 [2012-08-04 10:07:43 - SDK Manager] Created AVD 'MAPAPP1' based on Android 2.1, ARM (armeabi) processor,
[2012-08-04 10:07:43 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
[2012-08-04 10:07:43 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=240
[2012-08-04 10:07:43 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=24
[2012-08-04 10:07:58 - SDK Manager] SD Card already present with same size, was not changed.
[2012-08-04 10:07:58 - SDK Manager] Updated AVD 'MapApp' based on Google APIs (Google Inc.), ARM (armeabi) processor,
[2012-08-04 10:07:58 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
[2012-08-04 10:07:58 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=240
[2012-08-04 10:07:58 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=24
[2012-08-04 10:47:07 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2012-08-04 10:47:40 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] res\layout\main.xml:0: error: Resource entry main is already defined.
[2012-08-04 10:47:40 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] res\layout\main.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
[2012-08-04 10:47:40 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] C:\Development\JAVAWorkSpace\com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity\res\layout\main.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-08-04 10:48:16 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2012-08-04 10:49:25 - SDK Manager] Deleting file C:\Users\Ogechineke\.android\avd\MapApp.ini
[2012-08-04 10:49:25 - SDK Manager] Deleting folder C:\Users\Ogechineke\.android\avd\MapApp.avd
[2012-08-04 10:49:25 - SDK Manager] AVD 'MapApp' deleted.
[2012-08-04 10:49:35 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

Is there a way to configure this so the xml.out files generated are deleted on error/exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is sometimes an error when building with Eclipse and Android XML files.

- delete all of the .xml.out files
- save and clean everything
- Close all of your XML files
- Click and highlight your project in the package explorer
- Then try running

I've gotten this error when I have the XML files open and selected and I try to run the Android project. I wish I knew more about why Eclipse generates those .out files. Let us know if this solves your issue.